# Is $x^2-2$ irreducible over R and Q?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

I'm not sure if it is valid to say that $x^2 - 2$ can be factorised to $2\cdot\left(\frac 12x^2 - 1\right)$ for it to be reducible in Q.

Though I know $(x + \sqrt{2})(x - \sqrt{2})$ works in the reals.

Comment: Note that $2$ is a unit.

Comment: It isn't. Over fields irreducibility of a polynomial means that the polynomial does not factor as a product of two polynomials of smaller degree.

Comment: By that definition, no polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$...

Comment: oh of course. So because the square root of 2 is irrational is it irreducible over Q?

Comment: Basically yes. I prefer to say that if it were reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, it would be a product of linear factors with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, and therefore would have a rational root. But it doesn't.

Comment: @rschwieb, $2\cdot (\frac{1}{2} x^2-1)$ is a unit times another element, hence it does not prove the reducibility of $x^2-2$.

Comment: @vadim123 Ok, I see you were addressing something else now :) Deleted my question.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you can factor it as $x^2 - 2 = (x+a)(x+b)$ , $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then:

$a+b= 0, ab = -2$, thus: $a = - b, -a^2 = -2$.

So: $a^2 = 2$, and this can't happen for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial is ofcourse reducible over $\mathbb{R}$ as it can be written as a product of polynomials of **(strictly)** smaller degrees.

Again, by **Eisenstein's criteria** it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$